# Django Model returning NoneType

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model Product

it has  two fields size & colours among others

```
colours = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
size = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
```

In my view I have

```
current_product = Product.objects.get(slug=title)
if len(current_product.size) != 0 :
    current_product.size = current_product.size.split(",")
```

and get this error:

object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

What is NoneType and how can I test for it?

Comment: "object of type NoneType" is something you can look up in the Python docs.  It's the constant None.  The model isn't return "NoneType", it's returning None, which is an object of NoneType.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NoneType` is the type that the `None` value has. You want to change the second snippet to

```
if current_product.size: # This will evaluate as false if size is None or len(size) == 0.
  blah blah
```

Comment: Cheers,
I thought I'd tried that. That's why I was trying testing the length. Ah well. You get this on the big jobs

Comment: You do at that. I like this idiom -- it eliminates an "or" that makes the code less readable, and that's easy to forget (as illustrated here :) )

Comment: Please use "is not None" rather than assuming that None is like False -- it make the if statement perfectly clear.

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't see any reason to test for None specifically in this case.  The purpose is to test whether current_product.size has any contents, and this does that more clearly than a complicated double-check for "is not None" and len().

Comment: @Carl Meyer: Exactly. "is not None" is the correct idiom when you're testing for None-ness, but if you're checking whether a list is both non-None *and* has contents, use the list as a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

NoneType is Pythons NULL-Type, meaning "nothing", "undefined". It has only one value: "None". When creating a new model object, its attributes are usually initialized to None, you can check that by comparing:

```
if someobject.someattr is None:
    # Not set yet
```

Comment: Calling it "undefined" is a bit facetious. The variable/name is defined, but it has no useful value.

Answer (score 0):

I can best explain the NoneType error with this example of erroneous code:

```
def test():  
    s = list([1,'',2,3,4,'',5])  
    try:  
        s = s.remove('') # <-- THIS WRONG because it turns s in to a NoneType  
    except:  
        pass  
    print(str(s))
```

`s.remove()` returns nothing also known as NoneType. The correct way

```
def test2()  
    s = list([1,'',2,3,4,'',5])  
    try:  
        s.remove('') # <-- CORRECTED  
    except:  
        pass  
    print(str(s))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Django, but I assume that some kind of ORM is involved when you do this:

```
current_product = Product.objects.get(slug=title)
```

At that point you should always check whether you get None back ('None' is the same as 'null' in Java or 'nil' in Lisp with the subtle difference that 'None' is an object in Python).  This is usually the way ORMs map the empty set to the programming language.

**EDIT:**
Gee, I just see that it's `current_product.size` that's `None` not `current_product`. As said, I'm not familiar with Django's ORM, but this seems strange nevertheless: I'd either expect `current_product` to be `None` or `size` having a numerical value.

Comment: In fact, Django will raise an exception in this case (Product.NotFound).